# Show an image in a UIButton on long press gesture

Tags: ios, uibutton, uiimage, uigesturerecognizer

I have the following problem. I have a `UIScrollView` on which I have a couple of buttons with icons set as images on these buttons. I have a long press recognizer attached to each button. How can I show a smaller delete icon on the sender button on long press gesture? My goal is to create the behaviour that is presented by iOS when the user wants to delete a specific application.
This is the code for a buttons (with images):

```
//set the button with the image of conference here.
UIButton * button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.frame = CGRectMake(3, 3, w-5, h-5);
CALayer * l = [button layer];
[l setMasksToBounds:YES];
[l setCornerRadius:8.0];
[button setImage:thumb forState:UIControlStateNormal];

button.property = confInfo;
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
button.tag = i; 
bView.tag = i;

//Add gesture recognizer to be used for deletion of conference.
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *pahGestureRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressGestureRecognizerStateChanged:)];

pahGestureRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 1.0;
[button addGestureRecognizer:pahGestureRecognizer];
```

This code is in a cycle (see i in the code). My long tap action is like this:

```
- (void)longPressGestureRecognizerStateChanged:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {

      switch (gestureRecognizer.state) {

          case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:
               NSLog(@"Tapped!!!");                    
               break;

          default:
               break;
      }
 }
```

How I can pass a button on which I clicked to this action to show the smaller X image on the right upper corner of the button ?

Answer (score 2):

Your gesture recognizer should be attached to the UIButton via its view property.

```
case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:
    NSLog(@"Tapped!!!");
    [((UIButton*)gestureRecognizer.view) setImage:thumbWithX forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    break;
```

Comment: If you set the highlighted or selected image to the image with the X, then you could simply changing the state of the button instead of change the image, which would be a little nicer, but depends on whether you are using those state images already.

Comment: @ Fls'Zen:I have an action on on click event so taht why I want to show a little image on long click. Also I have a little view on which is this button, and the image with the X is actually a button with action.